# What would happen if a negative voltage is given to an op amp adder circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, adder

Would it subtract that voltage because it would reduce the total current going on the feedback resistor ?

Comment: Adding a negative is the same as subtracting a positive.  An adder (with sufficient input and output ranges) will add your negative voltage just fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are both inverting and non-inverting summing amplifiers, so the effect on the current through the feedback resistor would be different. Also, you can't talk about "reducing" a current without specifying its direction or clarifying that you mean the **magnitude** of the current.

Comment: Welcome. If you provide a schematic (use the schematic editor button- it's quite easy to use) with voltage sources, net names where necessary, and part numbers on it, it will be possible to provide a better answer.